# Adding App from SharePoint Store + SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am planning to add few apps to my team site from the SharePoint app store.

When I navigate to the store from Add an app option from the top right pane, I get the below error:

**Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps.**

I navigated to the service application and all the below service have started:
App Management Service 
Work Management Service Application etc.

Let me know a resolution so that I can integrate some important apps to my team site.

Thanks and Regards,
Alex

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: See this also: http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Apps rely on the App Management and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings service applications. These service applications use the multi-tenancy features to provide app permissions and create the sub domains for apps

There is a great TechNet Article on [Configure the Subscription Settings and App Management service applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236(v=office.15).aspx)

Other than that double check your SSL certificates.

Let us know if have an issue.

Regards,

Vince